# Cefsharp input type seems to be always text

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to display a numeric only keyboard when the HTML input type is numeric. However `VirtualKeyboardRequested()` always seem to return `ev.TextInputMode` as "text".

The html is

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="numeric"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I then tried to use JavasScript to get the type and I still always get text.

```js
var result = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("(() => { var element = document.activeElement; return element.type; })();");
```

Is this a bug in CefSharp? How can I get the actual type of the input element?

Comment: Try to give element name and check that activeElement is the same as input.

Comment: ok its my bad...type should be number not numeric. However seems like the TextInputMode  is always default so there is some issue there. However I can use the javascript to get the actual type myself.

Comment: Try adding the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode attribute